# Как поделиться контейнером Docker с другим пользователем

Tags: docker, docker-compose

не могу разобраться как мне поделиться контейнером.
Скорее всего я запутался в терминологии, поэтому не могу найти ответа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: поделиться можно не контейнером, а образом, его можно загрузить на Docker Hub.

Comment: Контейнер можно экспортировать `docker save`. Получатель импортирует контейнер командой `docker load`

Answer (score 0):

### Вариант первый:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/docker-compose-exportsave-images-and-move-to-another-machine

### Вариант второй:

закинуть файлы вашего проекта(со всеми DockerFile) в git. Скачать этот репозиторий на другой машине. И запустить Docker. Docker самостоятельно подтянет необходимые образы.